# Asymptote cannot draw label: camera too close

Tags: asymptote

I get a strange error (`Camera too close`) when I try to draw a label in 3D with Asymptote.

This is my MWE

```cpp
settings.toolbar=true;
import graph3;
size(200,0);

currentprojection=perspective(
    camera=(1.48,-4.79,3.28),
    up=(-0.00,0.00,0.002),
    target=(0.02,-0.008,-0.018),
    zoom=0.25,
    angle=20.85,
    autoadjust=false);

// Domain
pair mn = (-.5, -.5);
pair mx = ( .5,  .5);
// Scalar field
real   fun(pair r) { return r.x^3 + r.y^3; }

draw(surface(fun, mn, mx, 8, Spline),lightgray, black+thick(), nolight);
label("$x$", O, N);
```

When I run this code with `asy tmp.asy` from the command line I get the following error

```
C:\Users\SomeGuy\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9/asymptote/three.asy: 2903.30: camera too close
```

If I remove the last line (`label("$x$", O, N);`) everything seems to work ok.

Do you have any idea what am I missing here?

**EDIT**

I'm using the Asymptote version that comes with my MiKTex installment on a Windows 7 machine. I have the following data:

- OS: **Windows 7 (x32)**
- MiKTex Console version **2.9.6972**
- Asymptote version (obtained with the `asy -v` command): miktex-asy version **2.44**.

I've tried removing the `settings.toolbar=true;` line, but that didn't fix the issue.

Comment: In my case, it works. Could you please specify asymptote version ? You can also try to modify the position of the camera.

Comment: Also please tell us whether you are using Windows or non-Windows. (The `-V` option (view) is automatically invoked on Windows but not on other operating systems.) And see if omitting `settings.toolbar=true;` makes any difference.

Comment: I also cannot duplicate the error (using a different version of asy on a different OS). A few more suggestions for altering the `currentprojection`: 1. Try setting `autoadjust=true`. 2. Try setting `up=Z`. 3. Try multiplying `camera` by 2.0 (this is a more specific version of O.G.'s suggestion). 4. Try using an `orthographic` projection instead of `perspective`.